# how to run junit only for tests with custom annotation?

Tags: junit, gradle, annotations

I have some tests that I want to run separately.

how can I add a gradle task that will run only these tests?

how can I add a gradle task that will run all tests but these tests?

I thought using annotations, but didn't see a way to combine it with gradle.

Answer (score 2):

using junit @Category and then gradle like this:

```
test {
    useJUnit {
        includeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryA'
        excludeCategories 'org.gradle.junit.CategoryB'
    }
}
```